# Adding Header to CSV file using Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a CSV file and data in CSV file looks like below its vertically formatted. that file is not having headers i want to add header to that file. when i tried to add using below powershell script its adding the header but its adding double quotes as well as its removing the spaces also.

My Data

```
booker12 ,rachel@example.com,9012,Rachel,Booker ,
grey07   ,                  ,2070,Laura ,Grey   ,
johnson81,                  ,4081,Craig ,Johnson,
jenkins46,mary@example.com  ,9346,Mary  ,Jenkins,
smith79  ,jamie@example.com ,5079,Jamie ,Smith  ,
```

output i am expecting(only want headers added)

```
Username,Login email,Identifier,First name,Last name
booker12 ,rachel@example.com,9012,Rachel,Booker ,
grey07   ,                  ,2070,Laura ,Grey   ,
johnson81,                  ,4081,Craig ,Johnson,
jenkins46,mary@example.com  ,9346,Mary  ,Jenkins,
smith79  ,jamie@example.com ,5079,Jamie ,Smith  ,
```

below is the script i am running and output i am getting is also below.

```
import-csv "O:\Temp\Import.csv" -Header 'Username','Login email','Identifier','First name','Last name' |
Export-csv "O:\Temp\export.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Output i am getting.

```
"Username","Login email","Identifier","First name","Last name"
"booker12 ","rachel@example.com","9012","Rachel","Booker "
"grey07 ","","2070","Laura ","Grey "
"johnson81","","4081","Craig ","Johnson"
"jenkins46","mary@example.com ","9346","Mary ","Jenkins"
"smith79 ","jamie@example.com ","5079","Jamie ","Smith "
```

In output formating is also removed and double quotes also added.

Comment: That's really more of a fixed-wicth data file, despite the presence of commas.  How are determining the max width for each column? What happens if a datum exceeds that width?

Comment: there's no formatting in csv. If you export a csv file from any apps like Excel, Libre Office Spreadsheet... you'll get no spaces around the commas. The fields are split exactly at the commas, no spaces involved

Answer (score 2):

You ask for "*output i am expecting(only want headers added)*"
using your example the following does what you ask.

```
$File = 'O:\Temp\Import.csv'
$Data = Get-Content -Path $File
$Header = "Username,Login email,Identifier,First name,Last name"
Set-Content $File -Value $Header
Add-Content -Path $File -Value $Data
```

Comment: `("Username,Login email,Identifier,First name,Last name", (Get-Content -Path $File)) | Set-Content $File` will avoid the need to read the whole file into memory

Answer (score 1):

`Import-CSV` only treats literals between double quotes. You need to define them as `"            "` or `"John    "`. So your original CSV file is poorly formatted for your needs. You'll have to either change it, or write your own import function.

With `Export-CSV` you're looking for the `-UseQuotes` option with value `never` or `AsNeeded`. However you'll have trouble with whitespaces again.

If you just want to add the header to the file, you can do the following:

```
$file = 'O:\Temp\Import.csv'
"Username,Login email,Identifier,First name,Last name`n" + (Get-Content $file -Raw) | Set-Content $file
```

Comment: Thanks Silbee. '-UseQuotes' is giving me error. i think i have old powershell. is there any alternative approch to remove quotes.

Comment: Yeah, usequotes was added only later (i think PS 7.0). There's no alternartive approach out of the box, you'll either have to write it yourself or look for solution online (powershellgallery.com for example).

Comment: BTW, do you only want to add the header ?